# How to use checkbox value asdata parameter in ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, checkbox

I need to reload a page when clicking in a submit button. What the new page should show depends on the checkboxes selected previously to the reloading.
My problem is that, when I click "submit", `$("button").click(function()...` takes the correct values but `$(document).ready(function ()...` takes always the values `true` (which are selected as default).

How can I save those values before the reloading so that I can use them on `$(document).ready(function ()...`? Can I send them as data parameter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedCheckboxes = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getNewForm.php?accion=value1',
        data: 'selectedCheckboxes',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
          alert("ERROR");
        },
        success: function(res) {
          //Do something
        }
      }
    });

  $("button").click(function() {

    var selectedCheckboxes = new Array();
    selectedCheckboxes[0] = document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
    selectedCheckboxes[1] = document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
  });

});
```

Note: I did `var selectedCheckboxes` twice trying to get different results, don´t know where I should do it.

Comment: There is no part where you actually reload the page, so I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here:

1. You have a syntax error in your code sample. Make sure the code you post to StackOverflow compiles and runs without syntax errors (assuming you're not asking why a particular code snippet is generating syntax errors :) ).
2. The `data` attribute of your AJAX request is incorrectly specified as the literal string `'selectedCheckboxes'`, which means that your browser will send the literal string "selectedCheckboxes" as the payload to your server.
3. In addition, as you correctly surmise, you don't correctly handle the initialization of `selectedCheckboxes`. Variables initialized with `var` in JS are scoped to the containing function, which means the `selectedCheckboxes` declaration inside your `click()` handler are never going to be seen outside it.
4. Also, you're getting the value of "checkbox1" twice; you probably want to get something named "checkbox2" or similar. Related: If you are just serializing the only inputs in the form, use jquery's `serialize()` method so you have less code.
5. If you're really reloading the entire page anyway, don't use an AJAX request to do it? Using AJAX for form submissions is common when you do **not** want to reload the entire page (see below), but for your stated use case, it adds complexity you don't need. Just have a simple form with checkboxes and a submit button, and let the browser do it's default action.

Here's an example of using AJAX to submit a form behind the scenes, without reloading the entire page:

http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/rLeGv/

Given the HTML:

```
<form id="checkboxForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" checked="checked" id="ch1"/>
    <label for="ch1">check1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2" />
    <label for="ch2">check2</label>
    <br/>
    <button>Click me</button>
</form>
```

This JS will submit a form when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getNewForm.php?accion=value1',
      data: $('#checkboxForm').serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function() {
        alert("ERROR");
      },
      success: function(res) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

As far as loading a new page with the previous selections, you will have to maintain the state somehow. Your options include passing the state back from the server, storing the selections in the browser's local storage, or a cookie. I'd suggest passing the state back from the server, but your use case is a bit unclear.

Comment: Ok, I´m reviewing them.
1. Sorry, I deleted parts of the code that weren´t causin the problem to simplify this, Imay have commited a mistake there.
2. That was one of my doubts, how data was sent. I couldn´t find any good tutorial on how to use `$(document).ready(function ()...`, any help so that I can read before posting again.
3. Ok, I´m going to check that.
4. That´s a typing mistake.
5. I´m going to see that.
I still don´t know why is the page reloading, could it be because I´m using a submit button?